# Add attribute checked for dynamic checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have dynamic create checkbox. Checkbox is to select the correct answer and add to the database in MySQL. How i can update input checkbox who is checked.

Adding checkbox, textbox and button for delete in JS:

```
function dodaj_odpowiedz(kontener){

  var kontener = document.getElementById(kontener);

  var znacznik3 = document.createElement('input');
  znacznik3.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  znacznik3.setAttribute('name', 'poprawnosc'+lp);
  znacznik3.setAttribute('id', 'poprawnosc'+lp);
  znacznik3.className = 'ClassPoprawnosc';
  kontener.appendChild(znacznik3);

  var znacznik = document.createElement('input');
  znacznik.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  znacznik.setAttribute('name', 'odp'+lp);
  znacznik.setAttribute('id', 'odp'+lp);
  znacznik.className = 'upload';
  znacznik.setAttribute('size', '50');
  kontener.appendChild(znacznik);

  var znacznik2 = document.createElement('input');
  znacznik2.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  znacznik2.setAttribute('name', 'usuwanie'+lp);
  znacznik2.setAttribute('id', 'usun'+lp);
  znacznik.className = 'upload';
  var funkcja = "usun('"+lp+"')";
  znacznik2.setAttribute('onclick', funkcja);
  znacznik2.setAttribute('value', 'Usun');
  kontener.appendChild(znacznik2); 

   lp++;
}
```

Adding attirbute for checkbox. I want effect for example:

input type="checkbox" name="poprawnosc1" id="poprawnosc1" class="ClassPoprawnosc" **checked**

so I was tried this way in jQuery:

```
 $(".ClassPoprawnosc").live("click", function(){

if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
{
  this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
  this.checked = true;
}
else
{
  this.setAttribute("checked", ""); // For IE
  this.removeAttribute("checked"); // For other browsers
  this.checked = false;
}
});
```

Now I have error :
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)

for line which is code :

```
 $(".ClassPoprawnosc").live("click", function(){
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live()` is deprecated. Use `on` instead:

```
$(".ClassPoprawnosc").on("click", function(){
```